# Enumerate equations alignment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, lists

[image]

The only thing coming to my mind is to use `intertext` and manually place counters. Is this really the only way?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\intertext`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}\mathtoolsset{above-intertext-sep=-\belowdisplayshortskip}
\item How can I align the equations
\begin{align*}
    a &= 2. \\
\intertext{
  \item Which appear in various items of \texttt{enumerate}?
}
  b &= a + 123.
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!! What's happening here? :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `eqparbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item How can I align the equation
 \begin{align*}
  \eqmakebox[L][r]{$a$}&=\eqmakebox[R][l]{$2$}
 \end{align*}
 \item with the equation
 \begin{align*}
  \eqmakebox[L][r]{$b$}&=\eqmakebox[R][l]{$a+123$}
 \end{align*} 
 \item With \verb|eqparbox|.
\end{enumerate}
You can make it more structured by defining macros for that.
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][pft]{\eqmakebox[L#1][r]{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\newcommand{\RHS}[2][pft]{\eqmakebox[R][l]{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Now you can align the equation
 \begin{align*}
  \LHS{a}&=\RHS{2}
 \end{align*}
 \item with the equation
 \begin{align*}
  \LHS{b+7c}&=\RHS{a+123}
 \end{align*} 
 \item using the macros \verb|\LHS| and \verb|\RHS|.
\end{enumerate}
The optional argument is an identifier. For each new set of mutually aligned
equations you need a distinct identifier. That is, all the left--hand sides and
all the right--hand sides with the same identifier have the same widths,
respectively.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: This is an addendum to [egreg's nice(!) solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521673/194703). If you consider loading `enumitem` (on top of `mathtools`), you can make things more user-friendly by saying

```
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\mathtoolsset{above-intertext-sep=-\belowdisplayshortskip}}
```

That way you do not have to add this to each `enumerate` environment by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\mathtoolsset{above-intertext-sep=-\belowdisplayshortskip}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item How can I align the equations
\begin{align*}
    a &= 2 \;,\\
\intertext{
  \item which appear in various items of \texttt{enumerate},
}
  b &= a + 123\;,\\
\intertext{
  \item and without adding something by hand whenever I use \texttt{enumerate}?
}
  b &= c + d+\frac{7\pi}{2}\;.
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{align}
a &= 2 \;.\\
\intertext{We're back to normal.}
 b &= a + 123\;.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Looks really cool! 2. Could you please add some brief comments on how this works for those who never used this command before? Namely, what does '[L][r]' exactly stand for? Are these the identifiers that you mention? Can we use more than a single alignment tab?

Comment: @mavzolej The first, capital `L` is an identifier, I used it because it identifies the boxes on the left-hand side of the equations. You can replace it by anything as long as you make sure that all left-hand sides of the same system have the same identifier. The `r` means "right-align", i.e. move the stuff to the `=` sign. I tried to explain these things also in the lowest part of the answer. Whether or not this is the simplest possible way, I do not know, but I am afraid that marrying `\intertext` to `enumerate` may be nontrivial, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Well, then see the next answer :)

Comment: @mavzolej That's a nice answer but of course it requires you to change things by hand. I was hoping that there is some way to avoid this. If you are loading the `enumitem` package, you could indeed turn this answer into something that is more user friendly by saying `\setlist[enumerate]{before=\mathtoolsset{above-intertext-sep=-\belowdisplayshortskip}}`, then you do not have to add this by hand whenever you use enumerate.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be have access to the widest elements on the left- and right-hand side of each equation and use a mixture of `\phantom`s and over`lap`ping. In your setup, `a` is wider than `b` and `a + 123` is wider than `2.`, so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  How can I align the equations
  \[
    a = \mathrlap{2.}\phantom{a + 123}% Widest RHS is "a + 123"
  \]

  \item
  Which appear in various items of \verb|enumerate|?
  \[
    \phantom{a}\mathllap{b} = a + 123 % Widest LHS is "a"
  \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above process is simplified via [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) (see [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521652/5764)) by capturing the widest element's width using LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` system through `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`.